# sampling dataframe based on quantile (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that I want to sample based on an argument `num_samples`.
I want to uniformly sample based on Age across quantiles.

For example, if my dataframe has 1000 rows and `num_samples = .5` I would need to sample 500 rows, but 125 from each quantile.

The first few records of my dataframe looks like this:

```
Age  x1 x2 x3
12   1  1  2
45   2  1  3
67   4  1  2
11   3  4  10
18   9  7  6
45   3  5  8
78   8  4  7
64   6  2  3
33   3  2  2
```

How can I do this in python/pandas?

Comment: Quantiles means 4 range `[0-25), [25-50), [50-75), [75-100)`?

Comment: Yes! exactly sorry i should have clarified

Comment: Can you share code that you have tried if you have tried?

Comment: I think those are called `quartile` not `quantile`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a column quantile which has `bin` for the `Age1`. Then use boolean masking and resample to sample from each bin, use `pd.concat` to concat the samples obtained for each bin.

```
labels = ['q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4']
df['quantile'] = pd.qcut(df.Age, q = 4, labels = labels)

out = pd.concat([df[df['quantile'].eq(label)].sample(1) for label in labels])
```

Prints:

```
>>> out
   Age  x1  x2  x3 quantile
4   18   9   7   6       q1
8   33   3   2   2       q2
7   64   6   2   3       q3
2   67   4   1   2       q4
```

P.S. For sampling n samples, change `sample(1)` to `sample(n)`.

Comment: quantile should be 0 percentile, 25 percentile, 50 percentile, etc. The cutoff should be the raw number 0,25,50,etc.

Answer (score 0):

From Pandas 1.1.0, there's [`groupby().sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html) so you can do something like this:

```
df.groupby(pd.qcut(df.Age, duplicates='drop')).sample(frac=0.5)
```